# Azure WorkerRole shared folder access denied

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

On Azure, we intend to deploy one VM with a shared folder. On an another worker role, we want to have a FileSystemWatcher monitoring this shared folder on that VM. Both VM and Worker role are on the same subnet and virtual network.

On trying a Directory.Exists test, it returns false. In order to get a more significant error we try to list the files but get this error:

```
<-> Error Access to the path '\\192.168.0.4\Share' is denied.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(String path, String userPathOriginal, String searchPattern, Boolean includeFiles, Boolean includeDirs, SearchOption searchOption, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
```

On the VM, we set the share accessible to "Everyone". WaWorkerHost.exe runs under "NETWORK SERVICE". When remoting in, we can mount the share using "NET USE" command. But as demonstrated above, it doesn't work from within the worker role. How can we access a network share on a VM from a worker role?

Comment: Using a queue is a good method for communicating between worker roles in azure.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I would suggest putting the file in blob and sending the path to the worker role via a queue or service bus.

Comment: Yet another possibility is to use Azure File Service. Create a share and mount it in both VMs and use that as shared folder. Then you should be able to use that shared folder from both VMs.

Comment: The use of a VM is for Proof of Concept purposes and we're well aware that from a cloud architecture it's far from efficiient. The point is that legacy systems we integrate with won't be able to push data in any other way. I'll try with Azure File Service and give you a heads up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to impersonate with Credentials of VM machine that is hosting shared folder. It seems that your application is not able to authenticate itself on the other machine and that is causing the error.